# C# GMap.NET screen of map doesn't move correct position

Tags: winforms, gmap.net

I'm trying to show coordinates by using longitude and latitude on Google Maps. But, after entering an example coordinate it always shows the middle of the earth but after scrolling down(zoom out) it shows the true location on the map but not going there. It stays middle of the earth, so I should scroll down and move to the screen where I want, and boom the marker is there. So , what I want is here when I entered an example coordinate moves automatically the exact coordinates with the given zoom, like Google Maps.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double lat, lng;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            gMapControl1.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
            gMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
            GMapOverlay markers = new GMapOverlay("markers");
            lat = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            lng = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);     
            PointLatLng coordinates;
            coordinates = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
            gMapControl1.ShowCenter = false;
            GMapMarker marker = new GMarkerGoogle(coordinates, GMarkerGoogleType.green);
            markers.Markers.Add(marker);
            gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);
            gMapControl1.MinZoom = 10;
            gMapControl1.MaxZoom = 100;
            gMapControl1.Zoom = 20;

        }
    }
```

After 1 click
[image: After 1 click]
After moving the screen manually to the coordinate
[image: After moving the screen manually to the coordinate]

Comment: `gMapControl1.Position = coordinates;` -- Configuration settings (`MapProvider`, `DragButton`, `ShowCenter`, Zoom settings etc.) don't belong in a `Button.Click` handler, move them to the Form's Constructor. -- Note that `GMapMarker` is disposable (for a good reason)

Comment: @Jimi thank you.